# Positioning a component in Vaadin Designer 3?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10, vaadin-designer

I use Vaadin Designer for framework 7. In this designer I can drag and drop a component and moving the component by clicking on it a moving it to the area I want.

[image]

And trying to do the same with the new Vaadin Designer 3. But it seems that AbsoluteLayout is deprecated and the replacement is Div. I drag a Div and on top of it a Button. But I can not move the Button by selecting it a moving it using mouse. Is this possible in Vaadin Designer 3?

BTW I dont want to position the Button using CSS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no AbsoluteLayout in Vaadin 10 and AFAIK not even a plan for such. As that isn't there and Vaadin Designer not supporting absolute positioning directly, this just isn't possible currently with Vaadin 10+ versions. Thus, if you need this feature, I suggest to go with Vaadin 8, which has many of most essential the improvements and will still be supported for many years.